# Java Servlet Appending to StringBuffer Unrecognized HTML code

Tags: java, servlets

How do I give data from one servlet to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after `?` is part of the query string. In a `Servlet`, each key value pair in the query string becomes a request parameters.

If you have access to the `HttpServletRequest`, you can access them with `HttpServletRequest#getParameter(String)`. For example

```
request.getParameter("myId");
```

Comment: I need the one that was clicked. Because retriving the data comes back as null.

Comment: @cryptomath Edit your question. Show us the generated HTML and point out which link you clicked.

Comment: Ok. Edited. The Class Name of the Servlet has been omitted. I would imagine just the method to be relevant.

Comment: @cryptomath You misunderstood. I want the generated HTML on the client.

Comment: There is no HTML or JSP. I am writting to a string buffer -- I am unable to clarify. Perhaps, take a shot in the dark? I the click to have a value to reference it in a different servlet.

Comment: @cryptomath How do you click on a link? In a browser? Right-click and select `View page source` (or equivalent). That is the content (HTML) that your client (the browser) received.

Comment: I clicked on the link using a href="". Basic stuff.

Comment: @cryptomath I want to see the actual HTML for that link. Does it contain a `myId` request parameter with a value? If not, you may be generating it wrong or clicking on the wrong thing.

Comment: EDITED AND SOLVED. It was just a requeset.getAtribute("whatever");